# Taxonomy Term description in views when "no results" (Haven't associated nodes)

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

need help with Taxonomy Term description when no results in views.
I'm using Drupal 7.44 / Views 3.14 and render content from node teaser template without using fields, and for showing description used *Header area* / *Global:Text area* / *Php Filter* and this code

`<?php
$view = views_get_current_view();
if (is_numeric($view->args[0])){
$term = taxonomy_term_load($view->args[0]);
return $term->description;
}?>`

But it's work only when term have associated node, but some terms doesn't have nodes and description not showing.

Maybe some one knows how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot about "Empty Results". insert code in "Global:Text area" and It's works. Thanks me for helping)))